# java invoke method throws InvocationTargetException using axis web service

Tags: java, web-services, gson, axis, invocationtargetexception

I'm developing a web service in Java using Axis to get all the news from google, here is the code:

```
String s = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/news?v=1.0&rsz=8&q=";
URL url = new URL(s + URLEncoder.encode("test", "UTF-8"));
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8");
GoogleResults results = new Gson().fromJson(reader, GoogleResults.class); //here is the problem
return "service ok";
```

Here is my Java client:

```
Call call = (Call) new Service().createCall();
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/axis/services/googleNews");
call.setTargetEndpointAddress(url);
call.setOperationName(new QName("method_name"));
Object answerWS = call.invoke(new Object[]{});
System.out.println(answerWS);
```

Without this code:

```
GoogleResults results = new Gson().fromJson(reader, GoogleResults.class);
```

everything works, otherwise I get a java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.

The Web Service properly works alone, the problem occours when I call it with a client using the invoke method.

Any idea?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, when you use an external jar in your java project you have to add it in the axis lib folder (path: /web_server_local_folder/axis/WEB-INF/lib). 
I resolved my issue adding the gson jar in that folder.